# Convert XML to a list of something

Tags: c#, xml, linq, api, linq-to-objects

I have a xml file coming from my php site as an api.

This is the xml that is coming back from my php application.

```
<xml>
<overzicht>
<item>
<sessieID>6</sessieID>
<onderwerp>Vrijwilligers, een uitstervend rasnn</onderwerp>
<omschrijving>Ode aan de vrijwilligers jjj</omschrijving>
<sprekerID>1</sprekerID>
<lokaalID>20</lokaalID>
<themaID>1</themaID>
<typeID>2</typeID>
<periodeID>2</periodeID>
<datum>2012-02-20</datum>
<maximaleInschrijvingen>1</maximaleInschrijvingen>
<spreker>
    <sprekerID>1</sprekerID>
    <sprekerNaam>Rik Torfs</sprekerNaam>
    <loginID>13</loginID>
</spreker>
<lokaal>
    <lokaalID>20</lokaalID>
    <campusNaam>Malle</campusNaam>
    <lokaalOpCampus>W10</lokaalOpCampus>
    <typeID>2</typeID>
</lokaal>
</item>
<item>
<sessieID>15</sessieID>
<onderwerp>VPKB</onderwerp>
<omschrijving/>
<sprekerID>6</sprekerID>
<lokaalID>2</lokaalID>
<themaID>1</themaID>
<typeID>1</typeID>
<periodeID>2</periodeID>
<datum>2012-02-20</datum>
<maximaleInschrijvingen>50</maximaleInschrijvingen>
<spreker>
    <sprekerID>6</sprekerID>
    <sprekerNaam>Dick Wursten</sprekerNaam>
    <loginID>18</loginID>
</spreker>
<lokaal>
    <lokaalID>2</lokaalID>
    <campusNaam>KHK Vorselaar</campusNaam>
    <lokaalOpCampus>A102</lokaalOpCampus>
    <typeID>1</typeID>
</lokaal>
</item>
...
</overzicht>
</xml>
```

This is my C# code. I want to get al list of Sessie.

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
List<Sessie> sessies = 
    (
        from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("overzicht")
        select new Sessie(
                item.Element("onderwerp").Value,
                Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("sessieID").Value),
                item.Element("omschrijving").Value,
                (Spreker)(
                            new Spreker(
                                Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("spreker").Element("sprekerID").Value), 
                                item.Element("spreker").Element("sprekernaam").Value)
                        ),
                Convert.ToDateTime(item.Element("datum").Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("maximaleInschrijvingen").Value),
                (Lokaal)(
                            new Lokaal(
                                Convert.ToInt32(item.Element("lokaal").Element("lokaalID").Value), 
                                item.Element("lokaal").Element("campusNaam").Value, 
                                item.Element("lokaal").Element("lokaalOpCampus").Value)
                        )
                )
    ).ToList<Sessie>();
```

I know my code isn't working with this exception.

"NullReferenceException"

Comment: I'm sure the exception has a stack trace, which should show you which conversion is failing...

Answer (score 3):

There's one fairly obvious problem to start with. Look at the very start of your query:

```
from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("overzicht")
select new Sessie(item.Element("onderwerp").Value,
...
```

That will only work if there's an `<onderwerp>` directly under `<overzicht>`. There isn't - it's under the `<item>` element. Perhaps (given the range variable name) you meant:

```
from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
select new Sessie(item.Element("onderwerp").Value,
...
```

Comment: @user1360664: Well it's certainly better than what you posted to start with... *and* you didn't tell us what you'd already tried, *and* you still haven't said in what way this "isn't working". Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - you need to put more effort into providing information.

Answer (score 2):

The query

```
 from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("overzicht")
```

will return a list of `<overzicht>` elements. `item.Element("onderwerp")` does not exist, you are missing the `<item>` element in between.

Simple fix:

```
 from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
```